# Excel makes my PC squeak when recalculating one particular workbook

Tags: microsoft-excel, audio

I have one particular excel workbook that makes my computer squeak (for the lack of a better word) when Excel recalculates it or any other workbook when this workbook is open. The sound itself is mechanical and somewhat reminds me of a harddrive head seeking, but I don't have a hard drive or anything mechanical except for a CPU fan. And I jsut cannot figure out what makes this sound. It's not that the sound is loud, distracting or anything but I really want to know what it is and how the excel workbook makes it. I consider myself an advanced user (not a pro though) when it comes to PC hardware and Excel, but this unsolved mystery Excel sound just drives me crazy. It's my work PC so I cannot disassemble it and check what's really making this noise but it doesn't sound like a PC speaker (the one on the motherboard). I can reproduce this sound on several computers at work but it's only this particular file. It's also a quite old (creation date 2010) xls file with several worksheets and no macros.
Here is a short video with me pressing random buttons followed by Enter to make Excel recalculate.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TEL-Sw6CoVc

Comment: I don't like the chugging noise, which sounds like the hard disk, and that your whole computer is shaking while it's going on. This XLS seems toxic.

Comment: Please go to Task Manager to check the performance of CPU and disk when Excel recalculates this file. Maybe you ccould save this file as an .xlsx file, or make a copy, and then split multiple worksheets into several workbooks to check this issue.